# Получение токена angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, авторизация, oauth, oauth2

Пытаюсь получить jwt токен от сервиса авторизации с помощью [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc)
Редирект между моим приложением и сервисом происходит в штатном режиме, но токен почему-то я не получаю, и не могу проверить, например, клеймы.

Ознакомившись с документацией и пройдя через ряд похожих друг на друга гайдов написал следующее:

**auth-config.ts**

```js
import { AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

export const getAuthConfig = (): AuthConfig => {
  const appUrl = 'https://localhost:4201/';

  return new AuthConfig({
    issuer: 'https://idsvr4.azurewebsites.net',
    clientId: 'spa',
    responseType: 'code',
    redirectUri: `${appUrl}callback.html`,
    scope: 'openid profile email offline_access api',
    showDebugInformation: true,
  });
};
```

**user-info-component.ts**

```js
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService} from "angular-oauth2-oidc";
import {getAuthConfig} from "../../../../services/auth";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-info-component',
  templateUrl: './user-info-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-info-component.component.css']
})
export class UserInfoComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.oauthService.configure(getAuthConfig());
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
  }

  logOut() {
    this.oauthService.logOut();
  }

  logIn() {
    if(!this.oauthService.getAccessToken()){
      this.oauthService.initCodeFlow();
    }
  }

  get claims() {
    const claims = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();
    return claims ? claims : null;
  }
}
```

Помимо initCodeFlow использовал также initLoginFlow, но это не дало положительных результатов.
Версия ангуляра 12, клиента OAuth2 - тоже.
Что я мог упустить?